# Why regex "[ \A]abc" doesn't match "abc" in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a space or the start of a string, using string "abc" for a demo:

```
"abc_some_words" match for "abc" at the start of the string
"some_words abc_some_words" match for there is a space before "abc"
"Aabc" don't match for there is a "A" before "abc"
```

so I write regex as "[ \A]abc" for "\A Matches only at the start of the string". As shown below, regex "[ \A]abc" matches " abc", but doesn't match "abc" in python.

```
>>> re.search(r"[ \A]abc", "babc")
>>> re.search(r"[ \A]abc", "abc")
>>> re.search(r"[ \A]abc", " abc")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb6fccdb0>
```

Comment: I want to match a space or the start of the string.

Comment: @zhengchl if you ant to match the beginning you can use `^abc`

Comment: So you want to match a space at the start of the string, and you're surprised that it only matches a space at the start of the string? Did you want to match an _optional_ space? If so, you need to tell the regexp that the space is optional, e.g., by using `?`.

Comment: This is a completely valid question. `\A` is a documented operator and it is not immediately clear that it cannot be placed in a character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `\A` does not represent a character or set of characters. Therefore, it (and the similar `\Z`) cannot be used within a character class (`[]`). If you put it in a character class then it will silently be treated as a capital A.

To match either a space or the start of the string, you may use an alternation instead: `(?:\A| )abc` (where I used a non-capturing group `(?:)`).

Comment: Rather than `(?:\A| )`, you might prefer `\b` to match a "word boundary" in a pattern (including spaces or the start of the string). That will also let you match `(abc_def)` or `'abc_def'` (where the `abc` part of the pattern is preceded by a non-underscore punctuation character).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the beginning of the string you can use anchor `^`. So, if you want to have a space at the beginning or abc you can use this regex:

```
^\s?abc
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oR2kC4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

`\A` -- start of string is the mirror image of `\Z` -- end of string.

The meaning of `^` and `$` can be modified by the `re.M` flag. They can either mean the start of the string for `^` or the start of each line; `$` can be either the end of string or the end of each line -- depending on the `re.M` flag.

However, `\A` is unambiguously the start of the string and `\Z` is unambiguously the the end of the string.

Suppose you have the string:

```
txt='''\
1 ABC
2 ABC
3 ABC
4 ABC'''
```

To match the ABC at the start of each line you may do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^\d\sABC', txt, re.M)
['1 ABC', '2 ABC', '3 ABC', '4 ABC']
```

But if you only want the first and the last line, you may do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\A\d\sABC|\d\sABC\Z', txt, re.M)
['1 ABC', '4 ABC']
```